# Why can't remove the dir that have been chmoded 777?

Tags: php, permissions

I have assign anyone the right to read and write.

```
chmod  777 -R  /home/test
```

An error occurred  When  to remove it with php function:

```
rmdir('/home/test');
```

Warning: rmdir(/home/test): Permission denied

Comment: Delete requires write permissions to the containing directory, in this case /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is likely that you have an ownership issue. The directory is probably owned by another user and group.

You can change this by using the `chown` command which stands for change ownership.

`chown user:group directory/file.extension`

Answer (score 3):

Having 777 permission to /home/test isn't enough, the process trying to remove it also needs to have permission to alter /home (since removing /home/test constitute a change to /home).